# Add a new offline server in IBM Process Designer

Tags: java, business-process-management

In IBM process designer version 8.0.1.1, under the 'Servers' tab, there is an 'Add a New Offline Server' feature. I added a server, but it dosen't show up in the centre pane as is mentioned in the manuals. Hope someone can advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First , try to restart the server , then try to make test connection on your data sources , then try to ensure if you have more than one node to sure that synchronized if all are successful try to define an offline server.